# Dynamically increment td id using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

How to give dynamic id values in serial order for td `id="Selected_Device"` in below code using jQuery?

I need to append each device status is on line or offline. I am getting different status values for each td but it is overridden because it has same id.I have included my ajax call.It will take mac length and check mac is online or offline and append result in respective column.Current code only overriding last status in each td cell.Because td id is same for all device.

```
    <td class="Selected_Device" id="Selected_Device">
```

HTML

```
<tbody class="parameter_table">
  <% @my_devices.all.each do |parameter| %>
  <tr id="tr_device_<%=parameter.id %>">
    <td >
      <input  type="checkbox" class="checkBox" name="checkBox_m[]" >
    </td>
    <td class="macaddres" style="word-break:break-all;">
      <%= parameter.mac_address%> 
    </td>
    <td class="Selected_Device" id="Selected_Device">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

JS File

```
function getDeviceType() {

   var selected_Device_Mac ;

 var selected_device_id = '';

         if ($('#PA').is(":visible")) {
         console.log("before")
         selected_Device_Mac = document.querySelectorAll(".macAddr");
         var k=selected_Device_Mac.length;
          selected_device_id = document.querySelectorAll(".Selected_Device");

  for (var i=0;i<k;i++){
 $.ajax({

         method: "GET",
         dataType: "text",
         url: "getDeviceStatus",
         data: {
             mac : selected_Device_Mac[i].innerText,
         },

         success: function(result) {
             if(result!==""){

                 if(result.includes("On-line")){
                    //$(selected_device_id).html("");
                    $(selected_device_id).append(result+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&#9989;");

                 }else if(result.includes("Off-line")){
                    // $(selected_device_id).html("");
                     $(selected_device_id).append(result+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&#10071;");


                 }


             }
        }

     }

 );

}
```

Comment: You should indent and format your code correctly, it makes reading easier and helping you faster

Comment: It would be better if you can explain question more, with some raw data examples that you expect to be.

Comment: added Js code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd completely rewrite your js code in following way:

```js
function getDeviceType() {

  if (!$('#PA').is(":visible")) {
    return;
  }

  $(".macAddr").each(function(index, macAddrEl) {
        $.ajax({

          method: "GET",
          dataType: "text",
          url: "getDeviceStatus",
          data: {
            mac: $(macAddrEl).text().trim(),
          },

          success: function(result) {
            if (result !== "") {
              var nextColumnCell = $(macAddrEl).parent("tr").find(".Selected_Device")

              if (result.includes("On-line")) {
                nextColumnCell.append(result + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&#9989;")
              } else if (result.includes("Off-line")) {
                nextColumnCell.append(result + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&#10071;");
              }
            }
          }
        })
```

It gets list of elements with class `macAddr` (BTW. in template you have `macaddres` class) and for each element it gets its content `$(macAddrEl).text().trim()` and then it searches for element with class `Selected_Device` which has the same parent `tr` as current mac element `$(macAddrEl).parent("tr").find(".Selected_Device")`

You can see [working demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wRZzGO?editors=1111) (omited ajax part, it just reads content of cells with `macaddres` class and fills cells with class `Selected_Device` with index)

**PS.** Since id has to be unique, you have to do

```
<td class="Selected_Device" id="Selected_Device_<%= parameter.id %>">
```

or (if you don't use it) you can remove id.

Comment: Thanks.What is the value I need to pass in index and macAddrEl.

Comment: you don't pass any value, jQuery does it for you - `$(".macAddr")` returns array of elements with given class, [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) calls that callback for each element, so `index` is index of current element and `macAddrEl` is current element

Comment: you can fork that codepen demo and play with it to see how it works

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
#in your view 
<td class="Selected_Device" id="Selected_Device_<%= parameter.id %>">

#in your js.erb
selected_device_id = document.getElementById("#Selected_Device_<%= parameter.id %>");
```

Comment: Thanks.Still it is overriding same value for all td cells.

Comment: I updated the answer use `getElementById` instead of `querySelectorAll`

Comment: Thanks.Now td id values are as expected.But it is overriding values again.

Comment: Do i need to make changes here?             $(selected_device_id).append(result+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&#9989;");

Comment: where do you set `result`?

Comment: 'result' controller Json response

Comment: selected_device_id = document.getElementById("Selected_Device_<%= parameter.id %>");  is return null

Comment: alert(selected_device_id)

Comment: Well I did this in a project it was showing the expected div

Comment: it should be in a seperated file with the extention `js.erb`

Comment: @NEL so please include this in answer, it may be the reason why it didn't work for OP. PS. I noticed by accident that you replied to my comments, if you include @ with someone's name then this person gets notified PS2. I'll remove my previous comments