# How to call Dynamic td value in jQuery/Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to call dynamic td id value using jQuery/Java Script?Below the code i am using html erb file.I am getting null when i am trying to call dynamic id.
alert(selected_device_id)

```
<td class="Selected_Device" id="Selected_Device_<%= parameter.id %>">
```

JS

```
 selected_device_id = document.getElementById("#Selected_Device_<%= 
 parameter.id %>");
```

Comment: Can you access `parameter.id` in JS?

Comment: i don't think.Is there any way to call this? Just i tried.

Comment: Could you give wider context? Would it be enough to get all `td` with class `Selected_Device` or how do you know which one element should it be?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54215068/dynamically-increment-td-id-using-jquery/54216203?noredirect=1#comment95258981_54216203

Comment: This i have discussed regarding this issue

Comment: Order of `selected_Device_Mac` and `selected_device_id` should match, but since you're using jquery, I'd combine [`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over macs and [`$.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find closest cell with id.

Comment: Ok thanks.Any example for this

Comment: I have added answer in that second question, because it would lack context here

Comment: Thanks. I am checking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different classname for td then you can try following code to get the id value

```
console.log($(".Selected_Device").attr('id'));
```